# How to render common form elements as a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC and have been playing around with various concepts.

My sample project involves creating an application that allows me to raise different types of requests. These requests, however, share handful of common fields and I would want to create a partial view to render these control instead of having to duplicate the rendering in every different type of request.

I have put a sample application in my [VSTS](https://dev.azure.com/hazz-san/issues/_git/partialview). I have created a partial view shared across different request types but, I have lost all server side validation on these common fields. I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to achieve a common partial view without losing the validation.

Here is a few snippets of my code, starting with my ViewModels

```
public class ComputerRequestCreateViewModel : BaseRequestViewModel
{
    public ComputerRequest Model { get; set; }
    public override BaseRequestModel BaseModel => Model;
}

public class ReplacementRequestCreateViewModel : BaseRequestViewModel
{
    public ReplacementRequest Model { get; set; }
    public override BaseRequestModel BaseModel => Model;
}


public class BaseRequestViewModel
{
    public virtual BaseRequestModel BaseModel { get; }

    //Common Lookups
}
```

my models:

```
public class ReplacementRequest : BaseRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string AssetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}

public class ReplacementRequest : BaseRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string AssetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}

public class ComputerRequest : BaseRequestModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string OS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Memory { get; set; }
}
```

One of my Create View

```
@model SampleRepro.ViewModels.ComputerRequestCreateViewModel
<h1>Request a Computer</h1>
<form asp-route="savecomputerrequest">
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_RequestFormPartial", Model);}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="Model.Memory" class="control-label"></label>
            <span style="color:red"> *</span>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Model.Memory" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Model.Memory" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="Model.OS" class="control-label"></label>
            <span style="color:red"> *</span>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Model.OS" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Model.OS" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary mx-3" />
            <a asp-page="/Index">Back to Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my common partial view looks something like this:-

```
@model SampleRepro.ViewModels.BaseRequestViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label asp-for="BaseModel.RequestOwner" class="control-label"></label>
        <span style="color:red"> *</span>
        <input asp-for="BaseModel.RequestOwner" readonly class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="BaseModel.RequestOwner"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label asp-for="BaseModel.DueDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <span style="color:red"> *</span>
        <input asp-for="BaseModel.DueDate" class="form-control" id="DueDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly />
        <span asp-validation-for="BaseModel.DueDate"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is BaseModel?

Comment: @DeepakMishra I have update the question with more snippets. The BaseModel is of type BaseRequestModel.

Comment: I think you should use Model.Property only because I could not see base  model anywhere in your partial view

Comment: But my partialview's model is of type BaseRequestViewModel (which has the property BaseModel). I hope I am making sense.